# Reference data from cell then timestamp it at certain times

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am currently using a script/trigger to pull data from another cell, insert it on a new row, then timestamp it.  The problem is after I run it the first time, the following data is timestamped at a different interval.  In the example below, I ran the script at 1423, but it then began timestamping at 1519, 1619, etc..

[image]

I ran it again at the same time and got these intervals:

[image]

so very inconsistent.

```
 function getB2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Data");//wherever the data is
  const A1 = sh.getRange("B2").getValue();//wherever the data is
  ss.getSheetByName("AMM Volume").appendRow([A1,new Date()]);
}

function ctrig2() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "getB2").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("getB2").timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }
}
```

This is the script/trigger I am using.

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it your intent to place the function in a cell as a cell function?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes.

Comment: If I run the script at 0200, I would like it to run every hour on the hour. 0300, 0400, etc..

Comment: if you are going to use the function as a custom function then it will not work from a time based trigger.  I don't see how your function will work as a custom function because it has no inputs and it does not return anything

Comment: Any idea how I would go about performing this?

Comment: I would write it as a standard function that I call from a menu or a sidebar button.  But then I don't use cell functions or standard formulas very much.  So this kind of question has a lot of answer and as such it falls out of the scope for this forum

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is explained in Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#limitations) for time-driven triggers:

> The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.

This is why from the first execution there's a slight offset to the second one, but the rest should run accurately every hour.

Knowing this we can think of a few workarounds:

- Dump the first result.
- Instead of `everyHours()` use [`everyMinutes()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyMinutes(Integer)). The precision loss should be smaller (seconds instead of minutes). However, the limit is 30 minutes so you'd have to take this into account and discard half of your results.
- You can also try to use [`after()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)). This sets the trigger to run once after a certain duration in milliseconds. You could set the trigger to 3600000ms and have it recreate itself. You will still see some inaccuracies in seconds but it should be more manageable. The code might look something like this:

```js
function getB2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Data");//wherever the data is
  const A1 = sh.getRange("B2").getValue();//wherever the data is
  ss.getSheetByName("AMM Volume").appendRow([A1,new Date()]);

  //pretty much the same but also run the trigger creation function
  ctrig2()
}


function ctrig2(){
  let trigger = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "getB2")

  if(trigger.length != 0) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger[0]) //delete the trigger if it already exists
  }
  //  create the trigger to run after an hour
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("getB2").timeBased().after(3600000).create();
}
```

I think this is the closest you could get to your desired accuracy. Over time there will still be a loss of precision since you have to take into account script running times and server response times, which you'll have to live with.

Comment: Thanks for the response! ill give it a go

Comment: Hope it helps. I accidentally left the trigger running over the weekend and the offset is now +2 seconds, but it didn't grow progressively, it just jumped after a few iterations this morning. I guess it's just expected from a web service like this.